# Ajax not working on links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 //  $(document).on('click','.contact',function() {
   $(document).on('click','.test',function() {
      //$('.test').click(function(e){
      // evt.preventDefault();
      //$('div').hide();
      var cat = '-10';
      var data = {
         'action': 'my_action',
         'category': cat
      };

    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {

    console.log('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
  });  
});
```

and my php code

```
function my_action_callback() {
   global $wpdb;
   if (isset($_POST["category"])) {
      $category = $_POST["category"];    
   }
   echo $category;
   wp_die();
```

}

So here is the problem:
I am trying to built a site in Wordpress and i am trying to pass the categories that I want to be excluded from the posts.

.test is a submit button with a url to my post page. When i click on it i get no response from server and ajax doesnt work at all.

But when i click .contact that its just a div that doesnt redirect to any page, my code works fine and i get 'Got this from the server: -10' response;

I have also tried preventDefault(). In that case i get the right response but no redirection to the desired page.

My guess is that it has something to do with the redirect to another page.

Any help would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the click with preventDefault then if you want to redirect then use window.location to get you to the next page

Here is my answer

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $(document).on('click','.test',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var cat = '-10';
      var data = {
         'action': 'my_action',
         'category': cat
      };

    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {

    console.log('Got this from the server: ' + response);
     window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
  });  
});
```

Comment: That seems to redirect me to a page that does not exist. I get a 404 not found error in console , Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Ok i replaced it with the actual href and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: can you accept the answer if it has solved your question?